# Get distance from eddystone beacon

Tags: ios, eddystone

I am implementing beacons in my app with google beacon platform. Currently, beacon can be detected from a long range. I need to limit the range of detection which is quite not possible right now. Other option I am considering to detect the distance between iPhone and beacon. Is there anything provided by google or open-source SDK which can help me achieving the desired behaviour?

Comment: You can do it using ranging, all beacons support that, as far I know

Comment: check this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/determining_the_proximity_to_an_ibeacon

Comment: I have checked that but it's not working. This code is not detecting any beacon.

Comment: apple only works with iBeacon. I am asking about eddystone

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is pretty sparse, but I have open source code [here](https://github.com/AltBeacon/ios-beacon-tools) detecting Eddystone on iOS and ranging beacons with it.

Here is an example of how you use it to detect Eddystone-UID:

```
var scanner: RNLBeaconScanner?

scanner = RNLBeaconScanner.shared()
scanner?.startScanning()

// Execute this code periodically (every second or so) to view the beacons detected
if let detectedBeacons = scanner?.trackedBeacons() as? [RNLBeacon] {
   for beacon in detectedBeacons {
        if (beacon.beaconTypeCode.intValue == 0x00 && beacon.serviceUuid.intValue == 0xFEAA) {
            // this is eddystone uid
            NSLog("Detected EDDYSTONE-UID with namespace %@ instance %@", beacon.id1, beacon.id2)
            NSLog("The beacon is about %.1f meters away", beacon.distance)

        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: Yes please, I would really appreciate that.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example and added a README to the repo

Comment: i have implemented as you instructed but it's not detecting my beacons. Method to check if byte code matched with beacon always returning NO.

Comment: can you log the beacon type code and serviceUuid?  What are they?

Comment: @davidgyoung thank you for the solution. But it is not logging my beacons. same beacons logging if I prefer ObjC demo code.